# Filtering via OData query in sharepoint Office365

Tags: sharepoint, office365api

We need to be able to filter on a submap in a sharepointlist.

I have tried with the following expression, but it does not recognize the field:

`"(fields/task eq 'offered') and (contains(url,'submapname'))"`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code":"BadRequest",
        "message":"Invalid filter clause: Could not find a property named \'url\' on type \'microsoft.graph.listItem\'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date":"2023-07-24T09:50:54",
            "request-id":"96dfef38-922b-47b9-b132-e271066ab1cf",
            "client-request-id":"96dfef38-922b-47b9-b132-e271066ab1cf"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any possibility to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the **SharePoint REST API** or the **Graph API**?

There is no `contains` method available. So what you want to do is not possible this way. However, you can use `eq`, `startwith` or `substringof`. I think `substringof` could be the solution for you?

With REST API :

```
https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('your-list')/items?$filter=fields/task eq 'offered' and substringof('submapname', url)
```

Check the documentation, OData `contains` filter is not supported:

- REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests?redirectedfrom=MSDN
- Graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http

Comment: I used the documentation from here:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_any

There it definitely mentions a contains method.
I am using ms-graph to access the list.

It does not complain on the "contains" function, but on the "url" field or item it cannot find

Comment: I think you don't realize that SharePoint REST API does not implement every feature of OData. Do you test my solution? Only Microsoft documentation should be used: and this documentation explains that `contains` is not supported. Feel free to post the complete API call and not just the end.